# How to remove an "unsetted" environment variable from a Conda env?

Tags: conda, miniconda

I tried to use `conda env config vars unset` to unset a variable. But I typed a wrong variable name which is `1`. Now the `unset 1` exists somewhere and everytime the environment is activated, bash will complain:

```
bash: unset: `1': not a valid identifier
```

How do I remove this `unset`? I don't know where it is stored.

Comment: Variables are set in the `${CONDA_PREFIX}/conda-meta/state` file. Not sure how the `unset` command is propagated, but I'd expect it would be manipulating that file. Maybe check that file and add details to the question. I can't reproduce this behavior, so please add output from `conda info` to the question body, or better, give us steps to recreate.